# How to resolve jar from Artifactory using an ant build with ivy

Tags: ant, ivy, artifactory

I've managed to cobble together a CI system using Jenkins with an Ant build system that uploads the resultant .jar to Artifactory using the Artifactory plugin.

I now need another build which is also Ant to retrieve the latest jar from artifactory using a target in the build.xml.

I can find lots of articles about how to upload but few about resolving.

The closest I have found is http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Ivy 
but this mainly deals with uploading in the vital areas, the screenshots are out of data (or my Artifactory is and I can't update it) and deals with getting ivy or pom files.

I'm an Ant/ivy noob so any pointers how to put the target together would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you already use ivy? And need to know how to resolve the latest version, or did you never used ivy before and need to integrate it in your build?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, I'm a total Ivy noob I'm afraid so I really need advice with both.

Comment: a few tutorials are also here: https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial.html. Your question is very broad, do you only need to resolve this one artifact or do you want to set up a complete dependency management with ivy, that also handles all other libs?

Comment: One jar artifact only. Thanks, I have scanned those tutorials before and I'll read them again with what I've since learned but I think it's more the integration with Artifactory that is the sticking point for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you already [installed ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial.html).

#### ivysettings.xml

You need to define a resolver to artifactory in a file called [ivysettings.xml](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings.html) (put it in the root folder, beside the build.xml):

```
<ivysettings>
        <resolvers>
          <ibiblio name="artifactory" m2compatible="true" root="http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-releases"/>
        </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

#### build.xml

In your build.xml I'd use an [inline retrieve](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html) (so that you won't have to write an [ivy.xml](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile.html)):

```
<project xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" name="myName">

    ...

    <target name="retrieve" description="retrieve">
      <ivy:settings /> <!-- needed so that ivysettings.xml is used-->
      <ivy:retrieve organisation="foo" module="bar" inline="true" pattern="lib/[artifact].[ext]"/> 
    </target>
</project>
```

This will download the artifact into the lib dir. For organisation and module take the values you find in artifactory.

#### organisation and module from artifactory

In this image from the link you gave, you can see how to get organisation and artifact from artifactory. It will offer you a dependency declaration box. Just check ivy and take the values from there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks oers. Sorry for not being clear, Artifactory is hosted on a server not on local host, I've added a credentials before resolver in ivysettings and change the root element to the URL, is there anything else I need to do? I looked in Artifactory for module and organisation but can't see them defined anywhere, whereabouts are they stored? Also when I try to execute the target as 'ant retrieve' I get 'failed to create task or type project cause the name is undefined'. Sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: @slipp3ry credentials are mostly not needed if you read-only, but that totally depends on your setup and is hard to answer remotely. I updated the question. The error may occur because you didn't specify the xmlns-part at the beginning of the build.xml (look at the example I gave).

Comment: Bang on about the XMLS, I misinterpreted. I don't get the Dependancy Decleration in my Artifactory, the jar is just in a folder called bin so I'm guessing my organisation would just be bin and module myjar.jar?

Comment: @slipp3ry it could be. Frankly I don't know how the jenkins plugin works. You seem to use [freestyle builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin), which I have no knowledge about.